# Caching computed responses in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, caching

I have a RestController returning some localized entities - like book titles and descriptions translated into the user's requested language.

```
@RestController
public class BooksResource {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @GetMapping("/books")
    public List<Book> findBooks(
            @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean active,
            @RequestHeader(value = "accept-language", defaultValue = "*") String acceptedLanguages) {
        return bookService.findAll(active, acceptedLanguages);
    }

    @GetMapping("/books/{bookId}")
    public Book findBook(
            @PathVariable String bookId,
            @RequestHeader(value = "accept-language", defaultValue = "*") String acceptedLanguages) {
        return bookService.findById(bookId, acceptedLanguages);
    }
}
```

I have a lot of different clients making the same request, but each client doesn't frequently make duplicate requests.

I'm looking for a way to cache the localized responses (fully computed/rendered json) by a set of request parameters and headers.

I know I can add use [Cacheable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) on the resource methods, and use a [KeyGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/KeyGenerator.html) to create cache-keys off of the `accept-language` header, probably media-type, and whatever other parameters I want.

However, this will cache the objects and not the rendered json (or XML).

I've read through [documentation on caching static assets](https://www.baeldung.com/cachable-static-assets-with-spring-mvc), but these are just about setting the cache-control headers.

I want to avoid the serialization of these objects if it's already cached.

I could change the resource methods to return a `ResponseEntity<String>` and handle the rendering myself, but I would have to change code in every resource method for every new media-type we want to support.

I've thought about using a [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html), but it deals with the response before it's rendered.

I think I can use a custom `CacheProvider`, but that seems like it might be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a `Filter` for this. Those could read the rendered output stream and could write to it as well. If you set it up with a delegating filter proxy then it could also reach spring services and annotations like that `@Cacheable`.

You might as well take advantage of using those cache-control headers you mentioned. In that case the consumer side will know how long these XML's are valid. Anyways, there are far better solutions for caching this kind of information like Varnish.

Comment: Yeah, a delegating filter proxy would work. Varnish would be better, but it's not an option for us.Thanks! Was really hoping there was an easier way.